# draw rectangle with mouse move with Konva in VUE

Tags: vue.js, html5-canvas, konvajs, vue-konva

This is the behavior I want to achieve in Vue.js Here is the Js fiddle example i am trying to make:  https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/ukqhf54k/

```
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
        ctx.beginPath();
        var width = mousex-last_mousex;
        var height = mousey-last_mousey;
        ctx.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+mousex+', '+mousey+'<br/>last: '+last_mousex+', '+last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+mousedown);
});
```

I am using a library called [Konva.js](https://konvajs.org/). Right now I am able to free drawing in Vue.js with Konva.js. But When I try to draw the rectangle with mousemove. It does not work correctly. I am not sure what causes the issue. Thanks for any help! Here is my work on
[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-free-drawing-7zsli?file=/src/App.vue)

This is the behavior I found out for my work. It only draws the rectangle after the mouse move event and then mouse click event.

Answer (score 6):

```js
<template>
  <v-stage
    ref="stage"
    :config="stageSize"
    @mousemove="handleMouseMove"
    @mouseDown="handleMouseDown"
    @mouseUp="handleMouseUp"
  >
    <v-layer ref="layer">
      <v-text
        ref="text"
        :config="{
          x: 10,
          y: 10,
          fontSize: 20,
          text: text,
          fill: 'black',
        }"
      />
      <v-rect
        v-for="(rec, index) in recs"
        :key="index"
        :config="{
          x: Math.min(rec.startPointX, rec.startPointX + rec.width),
          y: Math.min(rec.startPointY, rec.startPointY + rec.height),
          width: Math.abs(rec.width),
          height: Math.abs(rec.height),
          fill: 'rgb(0,0,0,0)',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 3,
        }"
      />
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>

<script>
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stageSize: {
        width: width,
        height: height,
      },
      text: "Try to draw a rectangle",
      lines: [],
      isDrawing: false,
      recs: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleMouseDown(event) {
      this.isDrawing = true;
      const pos = this.$refs.stage.getNode().getPointerPosition();
      this.setRecs([
        ...this.recs,
        { startPointX: pos.x, startPointY: pos.y, width: 0, height: 0 },
      ]);
    },
    handleMouseUp() {
      this.isDrawing = false;
    },
    setRecs(element) {
      this.recs = element;
    },
    handleMouseMove(event) {
      // no drawing - skipping
      if (!this.isDrawing) {
        return;
      }
      // console.log(event);
      const point = this.$refs.stage.getNode().getPointerPosition();
      // handle  rectangle part
      let curRec = this.recs[this.recs.length - 1];
      curRec.width = point.x - curRec.startPointX;
      curRec.height = point.y - curRec.startPointY;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-drawings-rectangles-ivjtu?file=/src/App.vue